# InvalidRequestError flask-sqlalchemy. Can't make SQLite table

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new to flask and SQLite and have very little knowledge of how they work.

Models.py

```
from datetime import datetime
from flaskblog import db, login_manager
from flask_login import UserMixin


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.image_file}')"


class PostIntmath(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.title}', '{self.date_posted}')"
```

These are the models I have defined.

I don't know why this is wrong but it gives me InvalidRequestErrors.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 'mapped class User->user'. Original exception was: When initializing mapper mapped class User->user, expression 'Post' failed to locate a name ("name 'Post' is not defined"). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'flaskblog.models.User'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.
```

My full project is at https://github.com/MGeureka/flask_web_app
HELP!!!

Answer (score 0):

When declaring a relationship, you must use the class name exactly as it appears in the class definition.

The reason SQL Alchemy can't find 'Post' is because the name you used is 'PostIntmath' instead.

Change this line

```py
posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)
```

to

```py
posts = db.relationship('PostIntmath', backref='author', lazy=True)
```

And your error will go away.

SQL alchemy allows you to define the mapped relationship class with a string in this way so that these classes can be in separate files and still work without needing imports. Behind the scenes, the library looks for all the tables associated with the `db` object and attempts to find one that matches the relationship string name you've supplied.